Having issue while building a preview in expo (React Native)
My app is running perfectly fine when using on emulator but throwing this error when trying to build it in expo
Running 'gradlew :app:assembleRelease' in /home/expo/workingdir/build/android
Welcome to Gradle 8.3!
Here are the highlights of this release:

Faster Java compilation
Reduced memory usage
Support for running on Java 20
For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/8.3/release-notes.html
To honour the JVM settings for this build a single-use Daemon process will be forked. For more on this, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.3/userguide/gradle_daemon.html#sec:disabling_the_daemon in the Gradle documentation.
Daemon will be stopped at the end of the build
Path for java installation '/usr/lib/jvm/openjdk-17' (Common Linux Locations) does not contain a java executable


Task :expo-dev-launcher-gradle-plugin:pluginDescriptors
Task :expo-dev-launcher-gradle-plugin:processResources
Task :gradle-plugin:pluginDescriptors
Task :gradle-plugin:processResources
Task :expo-dev-launcher-gradle-plugin:compileKotlin
Task :expo-dev-launcher-gradle-plugin:compileJava
NO-SOURCE
Task :expo-dev-launcher-gradle-plugin:classes
Task :expo-dev-launcher-gradle-plugin:jar
Task :expo-dev-launcher-gradle-plugin:inspectClassesForKotlinIC
Task :gradle-plugin:compileKotlin
Task :gradle-plugin:compileJava NO-SOURCE
Task :gradle-plugin:classes
Task :gradle-plugin:jar
Task :gradle-plugin:inspectClassesForKotlinIC
Configure project :app
ℹ️  Applying gradle plugin 'expo-dev-launcher-gradle-plugin' (expo-dev-launcher@3.6.9)
Path for java installation '/usr/lib/jvm/openjdk-17' (Common Linux Locations) does not contain a java executable
FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.
1: Task failed with an exception.



Where:
Build file '/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-structured-headers/android/build.gradle' line: 40
What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':expo-structured-headers'.



Could not set unknown property 'classifier' for task ':expo-structured-headers:androidSourcesJar' of type org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.

Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or
--debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
==============================================================================
2: Task failed with an exception.



Where:
Script '/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/ExpoModulesCorePlugin.gradle' line: 65
What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':expo'.


Could not get unknown property 'release' for SoftwareComponent container of type org.gradle.api.internal.component.DefaultSoftwareComponentContainer.


Try:


Run with
--stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with
--scan
to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
==============================================================================
BUILD FAILED in 2m 23s
10 actionable tasks: 10 executed
Error: Gradle build failed with unknown error. See logs for the "Run gradlew" phase for more information.

I have tried removing few packages I installed since the last time I used build but still I havent found any solution to this problem.

Do you have Java installed on your machine?
Daemon will be stopped at the end of the build Path for java installation '/usr/lib/jvm/openjdk-17' (Common Linux Locations) does not contain a java executable
The error message indicates that the path for the Java installation does not contain a Java executable.
You should verify that Java is correctly installed and the env vars on your system.
